# Left align and right align h2 with css class in one line

Tags: html, css

I am trying to left and right align some text on a single line. I am able to align it but my CSS is not going across the entire line.

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/rp4yt5oz/) is a jsFiddle. The "Test" line is how it looks normally but i want to align text on the left and right. I am able to align text on the left and right but the grey bar does not go all the way across. I want the entire line to be a grey bar and not just the text.

**HTML**

```
<h2>Test</h2>

<div>
    <h2 class="alignleft">A</h2>
    <h2 class="alignright">B</h2>    
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
h2 {
    background-color: #555;
    color: #FFF;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    margin: 20px 0;
    padding: 5px;
}

.alignleft {

    float: left;
}

.alignright {

    float: right;
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: Are you saying you want the A and B in the grey bar? I'm confused on what youre wanting.

Comment: Yes that is correct.

Comment: Do you want them both to be in one line?

Comment: Yes. 1 grey bar with "A" on left and "B" on right on a single line

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than making a massive change to your code. Simply give the div the `background-color` attribute and clear the floating elements with `clear:both;` on a break or any element to make it recognize the elements.

Here is a working JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fLj5qvc7/

HTML

```
<div>
    <h2 class="alignleft">A</h2>
    <h2 class="alignright">B</h2>    
    <br style="clear:both;" />
</div>
```

CSS

```
h2 {
    color: #FFF;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    padding: 5px;
    margin:0;
}

div {
    background-color: #555;
}

.alignleft {

    float: left;
}

.alignright {

    float: right;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

One solution using to `h2` elements inside `div` position absolute(without change html structure):

```css
h2 {
  background-color: #555;
  color: #FFF;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  margin: 20px 0;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 90%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
div > h2 {
  width: 5%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 8px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 37px;
  line-height: 37px;
  text-align: center;
}
div > h2:last-child {
  right: 9px;
}
```

```html
<h2>Test</h2> 
<!-- How it looks normally -->
<div>
  <h2 class="alignleft">A</h2>

  <h2 class="alignright">B</h2> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest, pretty much at its simplest:

```css
div {
  /* forcing the element to clear floats: */
  clear: both;
  /* to force the <div> to wrap around its floated elements: */
  overflow: hidden;
  /* to float right, an element has to appear earlier in the
     HTML than float left content; so instead we align the
     text to the right of the parent: */
  text-align: right;
  background-color: #aaa;
  margin-bottom: 10vh;
}
h2.alignleft {
  /* float this element off to the left: */
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<h2>Just a &lt;h2&gt;, without classes</h2>
<h2 class="alignleft">Text in just &lt;h2&gt;</h2>
<div>
  <h2 class="alignleft">Text in both &lt;h2&gt; and &lt;div&gt;</h2>
</div>
<div>
  <h2 class="alignleft">A</h2>
  <h2 class="alignright">B</h2> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like this:

**HTML**

```
<div>
    <h2 class="alignleft">A</h2>
    <h2 class="alignright">B</h2>    
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
h2 {
    background-color: #555;
    color: #FFF;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    margin: 0;
}

.align {
    background-color: #555;
    margin: 20px 0;
    padding: 5px;
}

.alignright {
    float: right;
}
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/SalGnt/yhreswv9/) is a live example.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is unclear about what you really want. What i understood is that you want Both A and B paragraph to fill up full length of the page. If so the its very simple you can use **display: block;** property in your CSS for both the Headings.

Answer (score 1):

Need to help CSS with the widths. Also, how you structure your HTML. Let me know if you have questions.

```
HTML

<div class="wrapper">
        <h2 class="alignleft">A</h2>
        <h2>Test</h2> <!-- How it looks normally -->  
        <h2 class="alignright">B</h2>  
    </div>
```

CSS

```
  wrapper {
            width: 100%;
        }
        h2 {
            position: relative;
            background-color: blue;
            color: #FFF;
            letter-spacing: 1px;
            width: 80%;
            float:left;
        }

        .alignleft {
           position: relative;
            background-color: red;
            float: left;
            width: 10%;
        }

        .alignright {
            position: relative;
            background-color: green;
            width: 10%;
            float: right;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes simple and old school is simply better. Use a table!

```
<table width="100%">
    <tr>
        <td align="left"><h2>A</h2></td>
        <td align="right"><h2>B</h2></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this:

**HTML**

```
<div class="h2-plate">
    <h2 class="alignleft">A</h2>
    <h2 class="alignright">B</h2>    
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
 .h2-plate { 
    width: 100%;
   height: auto;
    position: relative;

}


h2 {
    background-color: #555;
    color: #FFF;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    padding: 1%;
    width: auto;
}

.alignleft {
    float: left;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
    width: 48%;

}

.alignright {
    float: left;
    width: 48%;
    display: block;
    text-align: right;
}
```

[See working example](http://jsfiddle.net/rp4yt5oz/3/)

Answer (score 0):

This example to indent to the right works well with my scss:

```
style="display:inline; 
float: right; 
position: relative;"
```

Answer (score 0):

With bootstrap (currently 4.0):

```
<h2 class="text-left">A</h2>
<h2 class="text-right">B</h2>
```

and voila, you don't have to do anything else